# Is there an event in a Spark List that lets me know what row is highlighted?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I know you can listen for the click event on a Spark List but I need to be able to listen for a highlight event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `ItemRenderer` support class [reference page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/ItemRenderer.html).  I'm not sure if there's a way to do this from the list level, but you ought to be able to bind `MouseEvent`s to those `ItemRenderer` elements within the actual list.